Powershell download file from Google Drive : Error 403
I have a file stored in my Google Drive that I need to download through  powershell. I have shared the file with its permissions being "Anyone with the Link"
The code I am using to download the file in powershell is :
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILEID?alt=media&key=APIKEY" -OutFile \PATH\TO\DOWNLOADEDFILE

The error I get is
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILEID?alt=media&key=APIKEY" -OutFile \PATH\TO\DOWNLOADEDFILE
Invoke-WebRequest : { "error": { "code": 403, "message": "This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded.", "errors": [ { "message": "This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded.", "domain": "global", "reason": "cannotDownloadAbusiveFile" } ] } }
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILEID ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

How to bypass the message "This file has been identified as malware or spam and cannot be downloaded." ?
Please help
To bypass the error & download the file

Change your URL to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILEID?acknowledgeAbuse=True&alt=media&key=APIKEY
See the documentation on the API:

Query parameters
acknowledgeAbuse
boolean
Whether the user is acknowledging the risk of downloading known malware or other abusive files. This is only applicable when alt=media.


same error as above. Sometimes I get the HTML file, which has the below information
===
Sorry, this file is infected with a virus.
Only the owner is allowed to download infected files.

Also it is a zip file containing an application-instraller.exe file

Well, are you the owner?

Yes I am the owner of the file
